# Passive sentence as a subordinate clause in Perfekt: arranging the verbal parts

Tags: verb, passive, perfect-tense

Given the sentence:

> Everybody knows that money has always been loved too much by people,

would you translate it in German as:

> Jeder weiß, dass das Geld von der Leute immer zu sehr *worden geschätzt ist* ?

I am particularly interested in knowing whether the relative positions of verbal parts, in italics, are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. *Geschätzt* and *worden* are exchanged. So

> Jeder weiß, dass das Geld immer von *den* Leuten zu sehr *geschätzt worden* ist.

And *Leute* is always plural, so I changed it: *von den Leuten*. If it is an academic exersise, it's ok, but otherwise I'd  take the agent, *die Leute*, out – who else could love the money? But that is a stilistic issue, I guess.